# How to print out special characters like å, ä, ö in C?

Tags: c, special-characters

If I try to print out "Ä" for example I get this character instead: õ. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (){

char name[20];

printf("Enter first name: ");
scanf("%s", name);

if(strcmp(name, "Carl") == 0){
    printf("Carl är bra!");
}
else{
    printf("Kung!");
}
return 0;
}
```

(By the way I'm using code::blocks)

Comment: What encoding is your source file and what encoding is your terminal? From previous questions, I think `code::blocks` has a weird encoding default (_ie_ not UTF-8.)

Comment: For starters, use `wprintf`, not `printf` to output strings with unicode characters to the console.

Comment: Second, make sure your source code itself is saved at UTF8, not ascii.  But between different IDEs, compilers, and source control revision systems, preserving the text encoding is always risky. I recommend using `\uNNNN` encoding for unicode chars when inlining direclty into source code.

Comment: To be fair, there are encodings that take 8-bits of `printf` that are also capable of printing unicode, (most notably UTF-8.) However, I think the terminal for `code::blocks` does not assume that as the default, `Windows-1252` or something.

Comment: If you have a console application and if it is about German umlauts (not å): The console works with the encoding `Codepage 850` . You have to write the umlauts with control characters, for example `printf("\xE1")` for the German ß. **But** : If there are more letters after that, these are unintentionally interpreted as well. Therefore you have to insert a space, which you can undo with `\b`.   printf("Oberfl\x84 \bche"); prints `Oberfläche`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, set the console mode to UTF16 and use `wprintf` with a wide string literal instead of `printf`.

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);  // this is windows specific

    wprintf(L"Carl är bra!");
    return 0;
}
```

However, as I mentioned in the comments about preserving unicode chars in source.  Better to just inline unicode chars with `\uNNNN` escape sequences.  With print statements like the following.

```
    wprintf(L"Carl \u00e4r bra!");   //0x00E4 is 'ä'
```

Comment: According to [_setmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-160) documentation, if you set `_O_U8TEXT`, you *still* have to use `wprintf`, so this answer is especially right.